# TYPO3: Where is "sitetitle" set?

Tags: typo3

Where is this "sitetitle" set:

```
return $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->sitetitle;
```

I found this line of code inside a ViewHelper of WapplerSystems\WsT3bootstrap\ViewHelpers\Site

Answer (score 1):

I found it by my self. Go to TYPO3 Backend / Web / Template. Just open the template setup   and you will find the field Website-Title. This is the $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->sitetitle. Maybe there is a parent template who sets the sitetitle!

Comment: In latest versions this title is set in the Site Configuration and also per language